# Adding a reusable block of code in Webmatrix

Tags: layout, razor, webmatrix

I have created an SQL query which checks if a user owns a record in the database, by checking if the querystring and UserID return a count of 1. This is the code below, and it works absolutely fine:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); 

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];
var rOwnerId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

var auth = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID = @0 and OwnerID = @1";
var qauth = db.QueryValue (auth, rPropertyId, rOwnerId);
}

@if(qauth==0){
<div class="container">
    <h1>You do not have permission to access this property</h1>
</div>
}
  
else {
    SHOW CONTENT HERE
}
```

The problem is that I need to apply this check on at least 10 different pages, maybe more in the future? I'm all for using reusable code, but I'm not sure how I can write this once, and reference it on each page that it's needed. I've tried doing this in the code block of an intermediate nested layout page, but I ran into errors with that. Any suggestions as to what would be the best approach? Or am I going to have to copy and paste this to every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Razor" way is to use a Function (http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/173/The-Difference-Between-@Helpers-and-@Functions-In-WebMatrix).

Add the following to a file called Functions.cshtml in an App_Code folder:

```
@functions {        
    public static bool IsUsersProperty(int propertyId, int ownerId)
    {
        var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
        var sql = @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM PropertyInfo 
                    WHERE PropertyID = @0 and OwnerID = @1";
        var result = db.QueryValue (sql, propertyId, ownerId);
        return result > 0;
    }
}
```

Then in your page(s):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); 

    var propertyId = Request["PropertyID"].AsInt();
    var ownerId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
}

@if(!Functions.IsUsersProperty(propertyId, ownerId)){
<div class="container">
    <h1>You do not have permission to access this property</h1>
</div>
}

else {
    SHOW CONTENT HERE
}
```

Comment: wow, i had no idea you could use functions like that, including queries in them. That is going to save me SO much coding. I'll have to go back through my code an "funtionify" everything. Works a treat. I'll have a proper read through the article on your site too. Many thanks (again)